# Save an item from a listview in to a textfile in android

Tags: android, android-listview, text-files

I am browsing an xml file from external usb storage (using otg cable, connected in the tablet/android phone) to be parsed.

Steps:

1. Browse for the file from external usb storage
2. Parse the xml file
3. Save the file in a text file

For the time being, I am now able to browse and parse the xml file then display the parsed file wherein it shows the needed information in a listview. Now, I want to save the displayed information as a text file and save it to the external sd card of the tablet. Here's the code:

**Model.java :**

```
public class Model {
String _model;
String _part;
String _sw;
String _desc;

// constructor
public Model() { 
}

// constructor with parameters
public Model(String model, String part, String sw, String desc) {
    this._model = model;
    this._part  = part;
    this._sw    = sw;
    this._desc  = desc;
}

// Set all methods
public void setModel(String model) {
    this._model = model;
}

public void setPart(String part) {
    this._part = part;
}

public void setSw(String sw) {
    this._sw = sw;
}

public void setDesc(String desc) {
    this._desc = desc;
}

// Get all methods
public String getModel() {
    return this._model;
}

public String getPart() {
    return this._part;
}

public String getSw() {
    return this._sw;
}

public String getDesc() {
    return this._desc;
}

//
@Override
public String toString() {
    return  "\n" + "Device" + "\n" + "\n"
            + "Model ID : " + _model + "\n" 
            + "Part Number : " + _part + "\n" 
            + "Software Version: " + _sw + "\n" 
            + "Description : " + _desc ;
}
}
```

**ModelParser.java :**

```
public class ModelParser extends DefaultHandler{
static final String ERROR = "Errors";
static final String ID = "ID";
static final String PART = "PartNumber";
static final String SW = "SoftwareVersion";
static final String DESC = "Description";

private boolean done = false;
private String currentTag = null;
private Model current = null;    
private ArrayList<Model> model = new ArrayList<Model>();

public ArrayList<Model> getItemsList() {
    return model;
}

public ArrayList<Model> parse(Context context) {        
    try {
        String file = ReadSystemActivity.getFilename();
        file.toString();

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        parser.setInput(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();


        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT && !done) {
            switch (eventType) {
            case XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT:
                model = new ArrayList<Model>();
                break;
            case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                currentTag = parser.getName();
                    if (currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase(ERROR)) {
                        current = new Model(); 
                        }

                    else if (current != null) { 
                    if (currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase(ID)) {
                        current.setModel(parser.nextText());
                    } else if (currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase(PART)) {
                        current.setPart(parser.nextText());
                    } else if (currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase(SW)) {
                        current.setSw(parser.nextText());
                    }else if (currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase(DESC)) {
                        current.setDesc(parser.nextText());
                    }


                }

             break;
             case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
            currentTag = parser.getName();
            if (currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase(ERROR) && current != null) {
                model.add(current);
            } else if (currentTag.equalsIgnoreCase(ERROR)) {
                done = true;
            }
            break;
        }
        eventType = parser.next();
    }

} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return model;
}
}
```

**And ReadActivity.java :**

```
public class ReadActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

public List<Model> model = null;
private String filename = "SystemInfo.txt";

String modd = modId.getModel();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);

    new LoadSystemTask().execute();

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // write on SD card file data in the text box
        if (isSDCardWritable()) {

              StringBuilder locationStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
              locationStrBuilder.append("Model ID: "+ modd);
              String locationStr = locationStrBuilder.toString();
        try {
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/FileReader");
            directory.mkdirs();
            File myFile = new File(directory, filename);

       myFile.createNewFile();
       FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);
       OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
       myOutWriter.append(locationStr);
       myOutWriter.close();
       fOut.close();
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Done writing to SD Card",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } 
      catch (Exception e) {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } }
      else 
        {
            // SD Card Not Available
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SD Card Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } //else

    }// onClick
    }); // btnSave
    }

    private class LoadSystemTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Model>> { 

    @Override
    protected List<Model> doInBackground(String... args) {

        // CALL XMLPULLPARSER & RETURN A LIST           
        ModelParser parser = new ModelParser();
        model = parser.parse(getBaseContext());
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Model> models) {

        ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Model>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, models);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
}



public boolean isSDCardWritable() {
String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(status)) 
{
  return true;
}
      return false;
} //isSDCardWritable

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub  
}
}
```

Problem is, I want to save the Id but I am getting a null value in the SystemInfo.txt when I click the save button.

Comment: Hello, What is your question?

Comment: its on the last part. I am getting a null value when I click the save button in the file that is generated instead of getting the model id,

Comment: Do you have external storage write/read permissions? http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: @Kenny, yes I do have a write permission in my android manifest. To clear things up, I am able to make a new folder in the external storage, and write or save the file named SystemInfo.txt. The problem is the model id is returning a null value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're storing model inside another object and trying to retrieve it from a new object.

This is where you're storing your model object inside `ModelParser`

```
current = new GarminModel()
```

whereas you're trying to retrieve it from a new object inside `ReadActivity`

```
GarminModel modId = new GarminModel();
String modd = modId.getModel();
```

Get reference to your Model arraylist by calling `ModelParser's` `getItemsList()` inside `ReadActivity` and from it try to get your model objects

---

Check position of below two lines in the code below

```
 ModelParser parser = new ModelParser();

 ArrayList<Model> modelList = parser.getItemsList();
              Model modd = modelList.get(0);
```

Note that you need to remove ModelParser parser = new ModelParser(); from LoadSystemTask

```
public class ReadActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

public List<Model> model = null;
private String filename = "SystemInfo.txt";
ModelParser parser = new ModelParser();
//-----------------

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);

    new LoadSystemTask().execute();

    Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
    save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // write on SD card file data in the text box
        if (isSDCardWritable()) {
              ArrayList<Model> modelList = parser.getItemsList();
              //-----
              Model modd = modelList.get(0);
              StringBuilder locationStrBuilder = new StringBuilder();
              locationStrBuilder.append("Model ID: "+ modd);
              String locationStr = locationStrBuilder.toString();
        try {
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/FileReader");
            directory.mkdirs();
            File myFile = new File(directory, filename);

       myFile.createNewFile();
       FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);
       OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
       myOutWriter.append(locationStr);
       myOutWriter.close();
       fOut.close();
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Done writing to SD Card",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } 
      catch (Exception e) {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } }
      else 
        {
            // SD Card Not Available
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"SD Card Not Available",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } //else

    }// onClick
    }); // btnSave
    }

    private class LoadSystemTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Model>> { 

    @Override
    protected List<Model> doInBackground(String... args) {

        // CALL XMLPULLPARSER & RETURN A LIST           

        model = parser.parse(getBaseContext());
        return model;
    }
```

Comment: I have tried doing this; 
"GarminModelParser modId = new GarminModelParser();
ArrayList<GarminModel> modd = modId.getItemsList();
GarminModel mod_id = modd.get(0); " but the app crashes due to IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Don't make a new instance of  GarminModelParser as "GarminModelParser modId = new GarminModelParser(); Instead create a global ModelParser variable that gets populated in LoadSystemTask.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get that. Isnt the variable "model" doing that?

Comment: The point is don't create a new object GarminModelParser and fetch from it. Instead fetch your list items from the object that has the parsed items. So you can just do model.get(0) inside your button click as well since it has the parsed items.

Comment: I do now get the value from variable "model". but i just need the first item. So when I did this: String modd = model.get(0); I am getting an error saying that I should change the type of modd from String to GarminModel. When I am doing that, the app gets a NullPointerException

Comment: Your model object is a List<Model>. Try changing modd type to Model or model type to List<GarminModel>. You haven't described what is GarminModel in your code

Comment: what's the relation between Model and GarminModel?

Comment: Ohh that sucks, sorry, all things are messed up. the GarminModel = Model. Sorry

Comment: I have checked your edits and tried this code: "ArrayList<Model> modelList = parser.getItemsList();
    Model modd = modelList.get(0);" and I am  getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: after the "private String filename = "SystemInfo.txt";"

Comment: you should put it inside on button click and ensure that parsing is done by that time

Comment: Done that, I am still getting everything. From Model Id to Description instead of just the model id. >.<

Comment: modd is an object of type Model. To get model id, use its getter method modd.getModel(); Also try to use relevant method names in your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience in helping me.